# Cypress selector with closest not working as expected

Tags: cypress

I can not select the proper select element which matches the label ('Special Class 1'). I have a couple of select items on the same web page with different labels but a similar structure like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody><tr>
    <td>
        <label>
            Special Class 1
        </label>
    </td>
    <td><div>
        <select>
        <option>One</option>
        </select></div></td>
    </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

My code looks like this:

```
    cy.contains('table', 'Special Class 1').should('be.lengthOf', 1)
      .closest('tr').get('select')
      .select('One');
```

But I always get the following since I have 5 follow up select elements (like the ones above):

```
cy.select() can only be called on a single <select>. Your subject contained 5 elements.Learn more
cypress/support/jsf/JsfWizard.ts:23:8
  21 |     cy.contains('table[class]', propertyLabel).should('be.lengthOf', 1)
  22 |       .closest('tr').get('select')
> 23 |       .select(option);
     |        ^
```

I tried already lots of things, also with parentsUntil. This is how I understood closest(). Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you:

```
  21 |     cy.contains('table[class]', propertyLabel).should('be.lengthOf', 1)
  22 |       .closest('tr').get('select').then(select => {
             console.log(select)
             })
```

Does it print multiple elements?
Maybe you can target the element by index afterwards? Or
maybe you can have an object with the options

```
{object: {option1: "abc", etc} }
```

and select the element with the key afterwards `object[option1]`?

Answer (score 0):

This `.get('select')` should be `.find('select')`.

The get command will always start searching from the root element `<body>`, the find command starts searching at the last subject, the `<tr>`.

```js
cy.contains('table', 'Special Class 1')
  .should('be.lengthOf', 1)
  .closest('tr')
  .get('select')    // start search over, ignore previous element
  .select('One');
})
```

```js
cy.contains('table', 'Special Class 1')
  .should('be.lengthOf', 1)
  .closest('tr')
  .find('select')    // search inside previous element
  .select('One');
})
```

Or use `.within()`

```js
cy.contains('table', 'Special Class 1')
  .should('be.lengthOf', 1)
  .closest('tr').within(() => {
    cy.get('select')
      .select('One');
  })
```